# String replace with delayed expansion (case sensitive) - Batch

Tags: batch-file, replace, case-sensitive, delayedvariableexpansion

I would like to write a really simple script to "encode" and "decode" strings, by replacing each character with a number, with delayed expansion enabled. But the syntax I use should be wrong as it doesn't work at all.

Plus, is there a way to perform a case sensitive replacement, in order to restore the original string ?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "alphabet=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "offset=15"
set "delimiter=-"

set "string=TeSt 123 tEsT 456"

set encoded=!string!
for /l %%N in (0 1 61) do (
    set "char=!alphabet:~%%N,1!"
    set /a "code=%%N+!offset!"
    echo !char! = !code!
    set "encoded=!encoded:%char%=%code%%delimiter%!"
)

set decoded=!encoded!
for /l %%N in (0 1 61) do (
    set "char=!alphabet:~%%N,1!"
    set /a "code=%%N+!offset!"
    echo !code! = !char!
    set "decoded=!decoded:%code%%delimiter%=%char%!"
)

echo original: !string!
echo encoded: !encoded!
echo decoded: !decoded!

pause
exit
```

Thanks!

Comment: Character substitution **IS** case insensitive. You have to either iterate string length **and** and compare each character with an `If /i` or use another script language better suited to the task.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks, it's what I thought. I decided to write the script with AutoHotKey, and I managed to do what I had in mind much easily and quickly! (By the way, I don't really like the batch language, it seems so complicated to do simple things...^^)